# Swift 3 - After writing custom camera view, Tesseract only returns gibberish

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ocr, tesseract

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2

I am building an app where the user can take a picture of a document and I use Tesseract to perform some OCR on the text.  When using the default camera view, Tesseract was able to recognize quite a bit of text.  Then, I decided to write my own camera view with AVFoundation in order to add some borders on the view to help guide the user to taking a proper photo and customize some other buttons.

[image]

Now, ever since then Tesseract has just been returning gibberish and not recognizing the text that it used to.

[image]

The actual code is fairly basic:

```
func doProcessing() {        
    // create a tesseract constant and initialize it to the english language
    if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
        tesseract.delegate = self

        // this takes the image and segments it into chunks so that I can recognize each corner of the document.
        let croppedTopLeft : UIImage = topLeftCrop(screenshot: stillPicture.image!)

        tesseract.image = croppedTopLeft
        tesseract.recognize()

    }
}
```

I've also tried converting the cropped image to `g8_blackAndWhite()` but that did nothing.  Any reason why my custom camera view is now causing problems and any suggestions how I can improve the quality of the photo?

**EDIT**

Okay, I figured out that it's probably something to do with the size or aspect ratio of the photos taken on the new camera view.  The size of the new pictures are 1080 x 1920 (I am using an iPhone 7) and the aspect ratio of photos taken with the normal camera view is 4032 x 3024 using landscape view and 3024 x 4032 using portrait view.  What is the optimal aspect ratio for Tesseract recognition.

Comment: What custom camera view?  You are only showing how you set a resulting image to OCR.

Comment: To figure this out, I recommend you save an image that you know works well (with the default camera) and then save an image with your custom camera and see if there are any noticeable differences in the two.

Comment: You can also save an image and use that image to do the OCR from the Tesseract image sample. I think the camera sample is not reliable.